# Why is UPnPy discover throwing AttributeError?

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-import, upnp

I am working with UPnPy, and I immediately notice an issue when attempting to discover devices on my local network. Here is the basic code I am using:

```
import upnpy

upnp = upnpy.UPnP()

devices = upnp.discover()
```

This throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    devices = upnp.discover()
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\upnp\UPnP.py", line 33, in discover
    for device in self.ssdp.m_search(discover_delay=delay, st='upnp:rootdevice', **headers):
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPRequest.py", line 50, in m_search
    devices = self._send_request(self._get_raw_request())
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPRequest.py", line 100, in _send_request
    device = SSDPDevice(addr, response.decode())
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPDevice.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._get_services_request()
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPDevice.py", line 23, in wrapper
    return func(device, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPDevice.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return func(instance, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\Projects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\upnpy\ssdp\SSDPDevice.py", line 171, in _get_services_request
    event_sub_url = service.getElementsByTagName('eventSubURL')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nodeValue'
```

I have been researching the cause of this but I have found nothing. I am using UPnPy version 1.1.8. I use PyCharm as my IDE. I've tried using previous versions of UPnPy but none seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a non-compliant UPnP Device in your home network that is serving a non-standard/broken XML at their description location, and `upnpy` was not smart enough to handle the parsing error and perhaps ignore that device.

That scenario is more common than you might think: many Smart TVs (LG ones for sure) have an embedded device that advertises as UPnP but their description endpoint answers *JSON* instead of XML!

Some suggestions:

- Use a different library or app (you could try [my own](https://github.com/MestreLion/upnp)), at least to identify the culprit. Check turn on verbosity and look for warnings and parsing error logs
- Use a scanner such as `tcpdump` to sniff network packets (UDP port 1900) for SSDP `NOTICE` advertises, and manually open each `LOCATION` URL in a browser to see if they're valid XML
- Selectively turn off / unplug devices you think might be UPnP-enabled, such as Smart TVs, Home Theaters, Video Game consoles, Routers, etc, to see wich one was serving the bogus XML.
- Edit your local copy of `upnpy` to handle that error, for example enclose the function/line with a `try/except` block and print some details about what is it trying to parse prior to the error.

Comment: Thanks.  Nothing like being able to view the problem.